# how does devise current_user work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to understand how the devise current_user method works because I want to generalize it to other models which would allow code such as current_forum or current_forum_thread.

To be more specific I am trying to implement a chat forum in Rails. I have a page showing all posts (currently none) for a specific discussion thread. That same page has the new post form embedded. The debug(params) shows:

```
action: show
controller: discussions
forum_id: '1'
id: '1'

discussion: !ruby/object:Discussion
  attributes:
    id: 1
    title: first discussion (thread)
    forum_id: 1
```

So the create method in the posts controller should know what the discussion id is. Yet this code in the controller does not work.

```
  1. @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
  2. @post = @discussion.posts.new(params[:post])
  3. if @post.save
  4.  flash[:success] = "Discussion post created!"
  5.  redirect_to '#'
  6. else
  7.  render '#'
  8. end
```

Line 1. raises the error:

```
Couldn't find Discussion without an ID
```

Also, on inspection it turns out that the @discussion variable is always NIL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting `before_filter :authenticate_user!` on top of every controller, and then do something like this:

```
current_user.posts.new(params)
```

This also requires relation `User has_many :posts`

Seems to work (not sure if that's the best way though).

Also, your error seems to mean that your prarms[:id] is nil, so check if it's passing properly. You should be able to see that in the logs.

```
# Discussions controller - show action
@discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
render ...

# Discussion show view
%ul
  - @discussion.posts.each do |post|
    %li= post.content # to output list of posts
= form_for @discussion.posts.new do |f|
  = f.input :content
  = f.submit
  # form to create new post related to this discussion

# Post controller - create method
@post = Post.new(params[:id])
@post.save!
render ...
```

Comment: That seems to be the issue. Where can I check the passing of the :id variable?

Comment: I only see that you put Discussion with id = 1 into the database. Don't see how you are getting it. If you have resources :discussions defined - you could get its ID like this: `http://localhost:3000/discussions/1`. That is probably how your discussion show action url looks, and that's where form is. My wild guess is that you are using `form_for Post.new` in your post creation form. If that's the case - you should probably try do `form_for @discussion.posts.create` (or `form_for @discussion.posts.new`). That will pass the id to Post automatically so you won't need to find it by ID first.

Comment: Still having trouble. Could the fact that the parent of the post ("discussion") itself a nested resource (nested under "forum") have anything to do with this problem? As Guy said I could use a hidden field to set the thread_id but I want to hold off for now on that solution.

Comment: just added how I would do it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more of a helper function, devise's way is to get the ID through the session, but you could do the same through the params hash,
i.e

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_forum_thread
   Thread.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

does that work for you?

Comment: The equivalent of your code raises the error -Could't find <Thread> without an ID-

Comment: well are you inside a thread's page? 
the params[:id] works when inside a page,
you can write `<%= debug params %>` inside a view to see what the params has is holding. Perhaps it is not set as :id?

Comment: Yes. The form to create a new post is embedded in the thread (discussions) page.

Comment: does params[:id] returns nil?

Comment: debug(params) shows that :id has a valid number. On second thought about your first question, even though the create post view is embedded in the discussion view post, creation is handled in a post controller. How can I tell the post controller where the call to create came from?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, what do you mean where the call to create came from? :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23444/discussion-between-guy-and-okyekyein)

Comment: Can you repost your question?

Answer (score 0):

Using the current_id with threads seems overly complex for this implementation, as it looks like a pretty simple nested resource.

The post isn't saving, because it couldn't find the discussion. Since you're on the Post controller and not Discussion, you need to be looking for the discussion with

```
@discussion = Discussion.find(params[:discussion_id])
```

The :id your searching for it with is from the post's parameters. It didn't find anything because you probably have significantly more posts that discussions. If it did find something it would be finding the wrong thing.

Another things on the check list to make a nested route work, is to get the routes right. Check them with 'rake routes' but it should look like this:

```
resources @discussions do
   resources @posts
end
```

This will add the routes so your form, which should look something like `<%= form_for [@discussion, @post] do |f| %>` can post/put to the discussion_posts_path.

Using the current_id like you got into is really scoping, and it's kind of messy, Ryan Bate's has an awesome video on Multi-tenancy with scopes http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes